# RemoteWebDriver Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

Tags: c#, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use the .NET binding for WebDriver to run tests concurrently through Grid2.  Running tests individually is no issue, however when running multiple tests through the Grid, the following error will occur occasionally, and when it occurs once there are usually multiple test fail for the same reason:

> Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms Build info:
>   version: '2.29.0', revision: '58258c3', time: '2013-01-17 22:46:35'
>   System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11' Driver info:
>   driver.version: FirefoxDriver

We have traced the source of the issue to where we create the RemoteWebDriver instance, which looks like:

```
            var desiredCapabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();

            desiredCapabilites.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
            desiredCapabilites.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            desiredCapabilites.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "14.0.1");
                try { _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://qwautomation:4444/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilites, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180.0)); }
                catch (Exception ex) { Notes.Add("AUTOMATION ERROR: This error originates from MasterSetup.cs (line 47)"); Notes.Add("AUTOMATION ERROR: " + ex.Message); Exception("AUTOMATION ERROR: This error originates from MasterSetup.cs (line 47)"); }
```

Where, qwautomation is the machine our Grid Hub is hosted on.  My assumption has been that the Hub is dispatching tests to a node that already contains a FireFox instance on a port, or that the sessions are not being disposed of properly by the JVM (as I can see folders with WebDriver session IDs in the node machine's temp folder).
I have written configuration files for the node and hub, which I will post below.  I didn't know if there would be a way to 'queue' a test if it could not bind to the FireFox port.

Hub

```
{
        "port": 4444,
        "newSessionWaitTimeout": 30000,
        "nodePolling": 5000,
        "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
        "timeout": 300000,
        "browserTimeout": 0,
        "maxSession": 1
}
```

Nodes

```
{
    "capabilities":
            [
                {
                    "browserName":"firefox",
                    "maxInstances":1                
                }

            ],
    "configuration":
            {
                    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
                    "timeout":180000,
                    "maxSession":5,
                    "hubPort":4444,
                    "hubHost":"qwautomation"
            }
}
```

EDIT: I have removed the "Version" capability from the DesiredCapabilities object and have not seen the error surface after several test runs.  I don't know if this is an actual solution, but it seems to at least decrease the risk of the Exception.

Comment: kill all firefox sessions and then try.. If it is not working uninstall firefox and again install the same.

Comment: I have reinstalled Firefox with numerous versions and that isn't a fix.  I'm looking for a long term solution, because it would not be practical to have to manually terminate sessions, or reinstall FF when this issue occurs, since we have tests running 24/7.

Comment: Kill all java processes before starting your tests.

Comment: What *exact* version of Firefox is it running?

Comment: We were running 14.0.1 on 6 nodes and 17.0.1 on 3 others.  We have code setup to target nodes, but I have seen this issue arise on all versions of FF I have tried, even earlier than 14.  Switching to Chrome has eliminated this issue, but I would like the ability to run tests on FF still.  I am wondering if this is an issue with the FirefoxDriver, since it appears that it is not releasing the lock of port 7055.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that rebooting the server usually clears up the problem. If the problem persists, try running fewer consecutive tests through the grid or upping the memory capacity on your Selenium nodes.

Comment: I've started to think this is an actual issue with the .NET bindings for Firefox.  We have switched to Chrome without any issues.

Comment: If it's any help, I've been using Ruby bindings for Firefox and I run into the same issues from time to time. It's intermittent and not reproducible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error many times and I discovered that I was actually the cause of it.

I typically run remote desktops from my development computer into my VMs to watch the tests take place on my grids.

When I toggle through windows on my local desktop using Alt-Tab and Shift-Alt-Tab I have done this selecting the VM precisely while Selenium was starting FireFox and inadvertently causing Firefox to start in safe mode because I was holding down keys.

When that happens, Firefox waits for confirmation that you really want to start in safe mode and never fully opens. All subsequent requests to open FireFox will fail until you confirm.

When the errors would occur, I used to stop the test and reboot everything starting with the test generator until one day I started with the VMs first, noticed the dialog and got to digging around for the cause of the dialog. It was then that I realized I was causing FireFox to start this way. Now I'm a bit more careful and don't have the problem any more.